# How to correctly remove and check for removal of an object

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, garbage-collection

I noticed something dangerous while working with AS3 - some objects (namely DisplayObjects / MovieClips) tend to remain in the memory and even perform actions after all references to them have been removed.

I work with `Flash CS 5.5` and `Flash Builder 4.6`.

After getting rid of all references (including removeChild(...) from the Document Class) some objects just seem to stay alive.

This question might come off as a bit broad - but what I am trying to understand is what can I do to MAKE SURE that an object is picked up by the Garbage Collector?
More so, how can I get some sort of feedback from the GC that signifies that a certain object has been destroyed? (For example, a console message)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Interesting article (and related articles at the bottom): http://www.nbilyk.com/flash-garbage-collection

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Removing the object from the stage, removing event listeners and setting all references to `null` should be enough - GC will pick it up when it is next executed.

It is tedious to keep track of all references, however (and remember this includes event listeners, unless you've set `useWeakReference` to true), if you don't have a standard way of doing it...  It is advisable to have a "destructor" function in every class, which takes care of cleaning up all variables and event listeners when an object is no longer needed.

You can combine these with events, too - I've come to think that it is good practice to execute your `init()` function on `Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE` and the `destroy()` function on Event.REMOVED_FROM_STAGE.  That way you have a clearly defined life cycle for stage objects, and if you make sure your `destroy()` method stops all animations and sounds, removes all children and event listeners and sets all member variable fields to `null`, you can be quite sure there's no longer any activity going on that could produce unwanted side effects.

By the way - if you actually *notice* any activity by an object you have removed, some references must certainly still be intact - how else would you be able to tell?

Still, there's no way to know when exactly GC will pick up a discarded object - this is managed by the VM, and you're not going to get a message when it is done. And it shouldn't be your responsibility to think about when to free memory - after all, that's exactly what garbage collectors were invented for!

If you make it a habit to clean up after yourself, your programs *will* unavoidably become more stable, consume less memory and ultimately perform better.  That's all that should matter.

Answer (score 2):

@weltraumpirat certainly has some good ideas and creating the init/destroy cycle as a working practice is a good one to adopt. There are other issues though that you might want to consider.

Creating new objects can be CPU expensive so using a blanket init/destroy method might not be the best way to go, depending on what your app actually does. You might want to consider creating a pool of objects and recycling them throughout your app.

This is a great article and tool to enable you to track objects in your app to see which objects still have references to them at any point in time.

http://divillysausages.com/blog/tracking_memory_leaks_in_as3

Comment: True, object pooling makes a lot of sense when you are dealing with a larger number of objects of the same kind, and you'd have to create/destroy them often - such as particle animations or the like.  You'd still have to "neutralize" the instances (i.e. remove all listeners and reset field values) before reusing them, though.